# An open problem of Hardy and Littlewood on $p$-integral means

Tags: cv.complex-variables, open-problems, harmonic-functions

In Duren's book "Theory of $H^p$ spaces" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=0268655)) in the comment section after Section 4, it is mentioned that Littlewood and Hardy proved in [Some properties of conjugate functions](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1932.167.405/html) that if $u$ is a harmonic function in the unit disc belonging to the harmonic Hardy space  $h^p$, $0<p\leq 1$. Then the harmonic conjugate of $u$, call it $v$ satisfies
$$ M_p(r,v):= \biggl( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \lvert v(re^{i\theta})\rvert^p d\theta \biggr)^\frac1p= O\bigl( \bigl(\log\frac{1}{1-r}\bigr)^\frac1p \bigr), \,\,\, r\to 1. $$

Furthermore they show that for $p=1,\frac12,\frac13,\dotsc$ the "big-O" cannot be improved to "little-o" by giving a concrete example. Duren then claims that this is an open question for other values of $p\in(0,1]$.

Given that the book is written in the '70s I would like to know if this is still an open problem, or if there has been some progress.

Comment: TeX note: please use "$p$-integral" `$p$-integral`, not "$p-$integral" `$p-$integral`, for presumably obvious reasons.  I have edited accordingly.